# Can someone explain the output of this program?

Tags: c#

Can someone please explain why this program outputs 0x00000004?

```
class AndAssignment
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int a = 0x0c;
        a &= 0x06;
        Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x8}", a);
    }
}
/*
Output:
0x00000004 

*/
```

Comment: A small tip. If you're going to ask for help from others then it would be a good idea to ditch the internet slang and write your question out like a normal human being. I've fixed it for you either way.

Comment: Here's another idea - type it in, compile it and see.

Comment: I thought they were asking _why_ the program has the output included in the question.

Comment: Good point. Hopefully this'll do to change the subject but keep the answer relevant.

Comment: I appritiate your help. Do you think a normal human being is a person that her first language is English? can you write perfect in my language ?

Comment: No, but I can more than likely form a question with reasonable grammar. If you want a relevant answer then you have to write a question in the best grammar and spelling you can manage. AOLBonics (Internet Slang) is a sure-fire way to getting your question ignored on any website.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

0x0c = 1100 in binary
0x06 = 0110 in binary
& operation is a binary AND which sets a bit to 1 if it's set in both operands, so:
0x0c & 0x06 = 1100 & 0110 = 0100 = 0x04
You can use windows calculator to see how integers is presented in different forms (hex and binary in your case). [More info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the basics of converting from number bases. Decimals are base 10. Binary is base 2. Hexadecimal is base 16.

Look at the following table for hexadecimal:

```
16^0 = 1
16^1 = 16
16^2 = 256
16^3 = 4096
```

Hexadecimals have the following numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c, d, e, f.

so  you have: 0C in hex, or just C.

```
16^0 x c (or 12) = 12 in decimal.
16^1 x 0 = 0
```

convert 12 decimal into binary now. Im just gonna show you simple addition pattern for small numbers:

```
2^0 = 1
2^1 = 2
2^2 = 4
2^3 = 8
2^4 = 16
```

so to make 12 in binary, you need one group of (2^3) and one group of (2^2). Therefore you have

```
1100.
```

If you convert it to decimal just like you did with hex, you'll end up with 12.

```
0 x 2^0 = 0
0 x 2^1 = 0
1 x 2^2 = 4
2 x 2^3 = 8

total = 12.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sara, he's converting between hexadecimal and binary. Have a read of this:
http://www.purplemath.com/modules/numbbase.htm

C (in hex) = 12 (in base ten)
1100 (in binary) = 12 (in base ten)